# Importing modules inside python class

Tags: python, class, import, module

I'm currently writing a class that needs `os`, `stat` and some others.

What's the best way to import these modules in my class?

I'm thinking about when others will use it, I want the 'dependency' modules to be already 
imported when the class is instantiated.

Now I'm importing them in my methods, but maybe there's a better solution.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

If your module will always import another module, always put it at the top as [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and the other answers indicate. Also, as @delnan mentions in a comment, `sys`, `os`, etc. are being used anyway, so it doesn't hurt to import them globally.

However, there is nothing wrong with conditional imports, if you really only need a module under certain runtime conditions.

If you only want to import them if the class is **defined**, like if the class is in an conditional block or another class or method, you can do something like this:

```
condition = True

if condition:
    class C(object):
        os = __import__('os')
        def __init__(self):
            print self.os.listdir

    C.os
    c = C()
```

If you only want it to be imported if the class is **instantiated**, do it in `__new__` or `__init__`.

Comment: If I import a module in a method (such as `__init__`), wouldn't it import that module multiple times if I create multiple instances? Therefore, would it affect the performance, compared to importing it globally?

Comment: Shouldn't it () after the __import, not []? I get the error "TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__getitem__'" when I use brackets. After I change it to () it works, but I have to prefix the imported module with the class's name, even when using the imported module inside the class, I would rather not do that. Any way around this?

Comment: @Samuel: Thanks for the correction, I fixed the import. If you want the imported object to be available globally, just use the normal `import` statement. That's not really a good idea with conditional imports though, as you can then have code *outside* the conditional that only works if the branch of the conditional with the import has executed first. If you use `__import__` as above, you avoid creating a global name for the object.

Comment: I see. I want a global name, but I want a conditional import. I'm importing the xlsxwriter module based on the output format the user chooses, so I don't always want to import it. Thanks for your help! This tells me what is possible and how to do it.

Comment: how can I apply `__import__` for from imports

Comment: @alper [See the example in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#import__): `_temp = __import__('spam.ham', globals(), locals(), ['eggs', 'sausage'], 0)` then `eggs, saus = _temp.eggs, _temp.sausage`

Answer (score 21):

```
import sys
from importlib import import_module

class Foo():

    def __init__(self):

       # Depends on the configuration of the application.
        self.condition = True # "True" Or "False"

        if self.condition:
            self.importedModule = import_module('moduleName')

        # ---
        if 'moduleName' in sys.modules:
            self.importedModule.callFunction(params)

        #or

        if self.condition:
            self.importedModule.callFunction(params)
        # ---
```

Comment: Why do we need `self.condition`?

Comment: @alper The value of the condition, "self.condition", decides if a specific module is needed or not. It may come from the settings that the application reads at startup.

Comment: can I add the module I imported in class to global scope somehow? so I could see it in dir() ?

Comment: @aleXela You may try declaring it before "def init" as class global as "importedModule = None" and later update it.

Comment: can u point me to some doc how to make it?

Answer (score 16):

[PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) on imports:

> Imports are always put at the top of the file, just after any module
>   comments and docstrings, and before module globals and constants.

This makes it easy to see all modules used by the file at hand, and avoids having to replicate the import in several places when a module is used in more than one place. Everything else (e.g. function-/method-level imports) should be an absolute exception and needs to be justified well.

Comment: This is for __unconditional imports__. If you only want to import them if that class is instantiated, obviously this doesn't apply.

Comment: @agf: There's very rarely a reason to import conditionally though. Especially with the modules OP uses, those are probably already in use by the implementation (try `python -c "import sys; print sys.modules.keys()"`).

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) (search for the section "Imports") official paper states, that `import`s should normally be put in the top of your source file. I would abide to this rule, apart from special cases.

Comment: Here's one special case. You want to fail gracefully if a user doesn't have a particular library installed. Suppose you have a script that does a bunch of stuff, and optionally it pushes logs to a log server. The library for the log server might not be installed. If that is the case you want the script to still run. If the user configured logging, we can print the error then and exit. But if the user didn't configure logging, the script should still be able to run without logging. Putting the import at the top of the script means it will fail all the time if the library is not installed.