# Subclass __init__ not seeing superclass conditonally-imported module

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop, python-import, super

I have a conditional import in a self-initialized instance of a superclass, but subclass cannot see the module (python 2.7):

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, arg1):
        self.attr1 = self.method1(arg1)

    def method1(self, arg1):
        if arg1 == 'foo':
           import amodule
           return amodule.method1()
        else:
            return 'not a dependency on foo'


class B(A):
    def __init__(self, arg1):
        super(B, self).__init__(arg1)
        if arg1 == 'foo':
            self.attr2 = self.method2(self.attr1)

    def method2(self, attr1):
        return amodule.method2()

if __name__=='__main__':
    b = B("foo")
    print b.attr2
```

This throws `NameError: global name 'amodule' is not defined`. `a = A("foo")` works just fine

Shouldn't the `super` call have executed `import amodule` in this case? (And using `import` should have put the module into globals?)

Comment: `amodule` is a *local variable*. Why would you think you would have access to it in `method2`? Also, the `import` statement does *not* bind the module name in the global namespace, but in whatever namespace the import statement is. Again, this would be *local to `method1`*.

Comment: doesn't `import` add /amodule/ to the global namespace of the currently executing module? (\_\_main\_\_)?

Comment: No, it doesn't Check this yourself `def f(): import sys`, then call `f()` and see if `sys` is in the global namespace, it isn't (unless it was already).

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: `A.__init__` calls `method1`.

Comment: @user2357112 ah, yes, you are right. I missed that. Anyway, the overall point still stands: `amodule` is *local to `method1`*

Comment: Why don't you just encapsulate the conditional `import` into it's own method, that *return the module*. Or maybe sets it to an instance variable. Honestly, not sure what would be prettier...

Comment: It looks like I was mislead by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861487/importing-modules-inside-python-class#comment42531679_6861854 when @agf mentioned global namespacing of the module by `import`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Doesn't import add /amodule/ to the global namespace of the currently
>   executing module? (`__main__`)?

No, the module is added to `sys.modules` but if it was imported locally then you won't have any references to it anymore. i.e the name `amodule` is now gone.

You could still access the module using [`sys.modules`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.modules):

```
def method2(self, attr1):
    import sys
    return sys.modules['amodule'].method2()
```

Or you could import it using `import amodule` again and it will be picked up from `sys.modules`.

---

```
# Here b.py contains
# print('Module b was imported')

def func1():
    print('inside func1')
    import b

def func2():
    print('inside func2')
    import sys
    print(sys.modules['b'])
    import b


def func3():
    print('inside func3')
    import b
    import sys
    print('Deleted b')
    del sys.modules['b']
    import b


func1()
print()
func2()
print()
func3()
```

**Demo:**

```
inside func1
Module b was imported

inside func2
<module 'b' from '/Users/ashwini/py/b.py'>

inside func3
Deleted b
Module b was imported
```

Comment: I could also make it an instance object too. importing this module is a bit expensive, unfortunately.

Comment: @cowbert Those calculations will only happen on the first import, later imports will pick the already imported module unless you delete it from `sys.modules`. Check the example in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `import amodule` on the first line of the program.

The reason is that amodule is imported in method1, method2 does not have access.

Comment: The import is conditional for a specific reason not mentioned (since it's irrelevant to the issue at hand).

Answer (score 0):

If you follow your code, you would see you don't reach method1().

When you create the object
`b = B(foo)`
You go through A.**init**() becuase the call for super(). However, your init of class `A()` doesn't include any import statements. Then the `A.__init__` part is done, and you continue with `B.__init__()`. The next command is a call to amodule object, which wasn't imported at all.

You can add an helper method, which checks if the arg equals 'Foo' and if so import the module. Then add a call to this function in `A.__init__()` function.

On another note, `__init__()` job is to initialize variables. It shouldn't return anything.

Comment: Where do you see \_\_init\_\_() returning anything? It does initialize variables, their initial values should be the return values from internal methods...