# How to import module during class initialization

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, import

I have a class that looks something like this:

```
class Foo:
    import_extra = false

    def __init__(import_extra):
        if import_extra:
            self.import_extra = true
            import extra

    def do_thing():
        # do some stuff

        if self.import_extra:
            extra.do_extra_stuff()
```

This class has some functionality that depends on `extra`, but I want to be able to decide whether this functionality is available or not when I first initialize the class, which happens once at the start of running the application. Unfortunately, I can't seem to figure out how to import `extra` for the whole class so that the other method can use it.

I designed it this way because the `extra` module might not be available for import in some cases. `do_thing` gets called quite frequently, so I'm hoping that it's possible to avoid putting the import statement there. 
Is there an easier way to do this that I'm missing?

Comment: It's hard to say with no knowledge of what ```extra``` does or what it returns. What particular functionality is important for the ```class Foo```?

Comment: The current approach is working, right?

Comment: No, the current approach gives me the error `NameError: extra is not defined` when I run `foo = Foo(True); foo.do_thing()`. The problem that I am trying to fix is that the import statement is in the scope of the `__init__` method, but I want the import to be usable for the whole class after initializing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem:

```
from importlib import import_module

class Foo:
    import_os = False
    os = None
    def __init__(self, imp):
        if imp:
            self.import_os = True
            self.os = import_module('os')
    def do_thing(self):
            print("doing thing")
            if self.import_os:
                print(self.os.devnull) # to verify that os has been imported

# check that it does actually work
print("running foo(false)")
f1=Foo(False)
f1.do_thing()
f2=Foo(True)
print("running foo(true)")
f2.do_thing()
```

It outputs

```
running foo(false)
doing thing
running foo(true)
doing thing
/dev/null
```

which is exactly the functionality that I want.

Here I'm using `os` instead of `extra` so that anyone can run it.
These answers helped me figure it out:

- [Python "import" scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106089/python-import-scope)
- [Importing modules inside python class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861487/importing-modules-inside-python-class)