multiprocessing when iterating over a DNA sequence alignment in Jupiter
I am trying to apply multiprocessing to a function to calculate the Shannon entropy for every position of a DNA alignment to speed up the process. It just keeps running without returning anything and I can not figure out what is wrong with my code.
Specifically, I'd like to incorporate Multiprocessing.Pool into my larger entropy class object that can be instantiated given any alignment file. I'm not sure if that's possible as I understand it's not recommended to use if __name__ == '__main__': in the class method __init__. I have been running this code in Jupyter, but I tried outside of a Jupyter environment as well running python 3.8.5
When I run the code below, I get the entropy array returned from the serial computation. However, when the parallel computation runs, I get no returns or errors, just infinite running.
I am pretty new to multiprocessing so any help would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if it's impossible to directly incorporate this into a class object without using a subprocess call or something to call a separate script.
from Bio import AlignIO
from multiprocessing import Pool
from scipy.stats import entropy
import pandas as pd
from time import perf_counter

path = 'path_to_aln_fasta'
alignment = AlignIO.read(path, 'fasta')


def calc_entropy(column):
  series = pd.Series(column)
  vals = series.value_counts(normalize=False)
  return entropy(vals)


def pool_calc_entropy(alignment):
    pool = Pool(8)
    entropies = pool.map(calc_entropy, [alignment[:, i] for i in range(alignment.get_alignment_length())])
    return entropies

start = perf_counter()
entropies_series = []
for i in range(alignment.get_alignment_length()):
    column = alignment[:, i]
    entropies_series.append(calc_entropy(column))

end = perf_counter()
series_time = end-start
print(f'series time: {series_time}')

start = perf_counter()
entropies_pool = pool_calc_entropy(alignment)
end = perf_counter()
parallel_time = end-start
print(f'parallel time: {parallel_time}')

print(f'pool time is {round((parallel_time)/(series_time), 2)} times faster than series time')



input example 'path_to_aln_fasta' :
>record_one
GGTTTGATGTATATGCTCATTACTTATTTGGATTTTTGATAGAAATAAAACAGCTTTAAGCGCTTCATTACAAGTCACGCAGTTACACCTGTATCGCAGTGTTTACCATCTTGAGGGTAATTTTGCATTAGTGGACAGCTAGACTCAGCCACGCCTATACCCTTCGGAACATCGAAACATACCAACCATGATATCGTCGA
>record_two 
ATGACTACTCGGTTACTTCTAATTGTTGCTAGCTGTACTTTGTGAAGTGAACAATAAGGTTTTAAAACCGTTAGACACAGTGCCTCTTTTAGGAAGATTCTTGATAATTTGCCCTGGTTTATGCATCGTTTGCACAGATTGACTTAAAGACTACGTCATAATAACTGCGCCTTGACTGCGGATTGAGCAATGCCTGCACA
>record_three
AGTAAATTTTATAGAGGTATTGCGCACCCTCGGAACTTTACAAAGCACAACCTGGATCACACTATTTCCGAGACCCACCTGACTGTGTTGTCGAGTTATCGATCCTATATATTTAAAGTTGGTTTTCAAAACATTTTTCGTTTGCGTTGTATACGGAGCCGTAGATAAGCGCATTTCGGTCATCAATCAGGGACAAATTA
>record_four
TTGAAATTAACATGCAACCTGACATGGTTTATTCTGCGGCATACAGAGAAATTGTGTTGATTGAACTGATTAGGATACTCCGGTCCCGTGTTTGAATTGTGCTAAAACCTGGTTAGAGATCGCGTCAATTCTCCATCCAGAAGAAGAACAATTTTAGGACCCGTTGTCATTTCCCTTAAAGGTTTTTGTAACAGTCCGAT


What happens, what did you expect to happen instead? Are the libraries you're using relevant to the problem? Have you tried writing a simpler example for yourself to validate that multiprocessing.Pool works as you expect? What do you expect the value of entropies_pool to be, and what do you do with it?

Are you running your code in iPython/Jupyter? multiprocessing.Pool doesn't work in Jupyter because it relies on a standard __main__ entry point, which Jupyter doesn't have, causing issues with starting new processes (see also: Multiprocessing example giving AttributeError).

That's a good point. I was testing the code in Jupyter first before incorporating it into my larger class object. Maybe I should test it inside the .py file first and see if that helps. The function to calculate the entropy without multiprocessing works fine. It should return a list of entropy values the same length as the alignment sequences.

This question is similar to: Multiprocessing example giving AttributeError. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

It's different because I'm trying to incorporate the Multiprocessing.Pool module into a class object, the specific methods shown here. I'm not sure if this is possible to do without using 'main' My code isn't producing and AttributeError, it simply doesn't return anything. I will make some edits to clarify

please do make your question including the class object that incorporates Multiprocessing.Pool module. In any case your script works for me as written by now

Thank you for the help. I haven't updated my class yet to incorporate multiprocessing. The class is large and contains different algorithms, but I want to speed up the entropy calculation portion. I'm interested in knowing how it works for you. If I run the code above inside a .py file outside Jupyter, I can get it to work. I'm not sure if it's possible to run it as an import or as part of the class object without having the script write the data that needs to be read back in. That's looking like my best option right now.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861487/importing-modules-inside-python-class
